# How to do master details report in devexpress C#.net?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to Know how do master details report in devexpress By Grouping

Note : I use Entity Frame work

Answer (score 0):

If you use the xtrareports, you may use it like crystalreport.
if you use the XAF framework's report, you can find it very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks , but I didn't use crystalreport